# How to parse grep output into an array and iterate over it

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I have some files with some lines that match these PCREs:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+):.*##(.*)$
^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\s*(\?:{1,2})?=(.*)\s*##(.*)$
```

So of course the grep output looks something like this:

```
<filename>:$1: ##$2
<filename>:$1 $2 $3 ##$4
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
<filename>
$1 $4 ($3) from pattern 2
$1 $2 from pattern 1
...
<filename>
$1 $4 ($3) from pattern 2
$1 $4 ($3 from pattern 2 # all pattern 2 matches first
$1 $2 from pattern 1 # ...followed by all pattern 1 matches
$1 $2 from pattern 1
...
```

Pattern 1 and 2 match targets and variables in Makefiles, respectively. The output will be printed formatted - for example, with `?=` variables in a different color. How can I get the grep output into an array that I can then manipulate to produce the output above?

I had to delete a question where I asked how to make it look nice, so I want to be clear that I'm **only asking how to parse the grep output into an array**. I generally think it's easier to help when I know what someone is trying to accomplish; if that's not you, please help me parse this output. If so, read on.

[This link](https://marmelab.com/blog/2016/02/29/auto-documented-makefile.html) shows a one-liner that makes an auto-documenting makefile. I hate to spoil the ending, but it looks 99% like this:

```
help: ## Display this help message and exit
     @grep -Eh '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort |
     awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "};
     {printf "\033[36m%-20s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

It looks specifically for targets with a `##` comment and uses `printf` to align the comments at column 30. I think it would be helpful to include the variables as well as the targets. I feel like this is a fairly noble cause, and there is a lot that can be done very easily to make the output look nicer than what that one-liner produces (probably with a one-liner!). I'm only asking for help parsing the grep output- this is one part of bash that I'm really bad at- but if you have any ideas on how to make the output look nicer, and it's not too much trouble to share them, I'd really love to hear them.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a real programming language like awk or even perl.

Comment: @rici I totally agree, I think awk would be a wonderful way to do it. Using a combination of awk and grep (so I have the filenames in $1 with a FS of :) and then maybe changing the FS to ##? I tried that with no luck. Everything in this repo is really well made because it's stuff I'm good at and I don't want to muck up this last part by being awk-ward!

Comment: In awk, the variable `FILENAME` is the name of the current input file. So you don't need grep at all, and you'll almost certainly find it easier to just use one tool.

Comment: By the way, `grep -E` does not implement non-greedy matches. I'm not sure what you intend with `.*?` in `@grep -Eh '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)`, nor what you're intending by including it in awk's `FS` (awk doesn't do non-greedy either, although it would make a certain amount of sense to use a non-greedy match there.) It would be easier to just use split.

Comment: Or maybe that's just code you borrowed from someone who doesn't know that grep and awk don't do non-greedy matches.

Comment: I copied that from the link and added the `-h`. I'm not very familiar with ERE's, so thanks for pointing that out. It could be, in PCRE, `^([^:]+):[^#]+##(.+)$`. That's where I was running into problems originally though.. Ideally I need to get `$1` and `$2` splitting on `:`, and then match everything after `##`

Comment: It wasn't until I decided to include variables that I asked here, because that's a totally separate regex and the printing is completely different as well. I don't know how to do both of those simultaneously.

Comment: `^([^:]+):[^#]+##(.+)$` is a perfectly acceptable ERE (although my comment about anchors applies to it, too.). With PCRE, which *does* do nongreedy matches, I'd write `(.*?):.*?##(.+)`, which is easier to type and possibly easier to read. (The anchors aren't doing anything. The match will start at the first possible place, which is the beginning, and extend as far as possible, which will be to the end.)

Comment: Well, in awk you would just add the lines from the different matches to different arrays. You can print the arrays out at the end of each file using an `ENDFILE` pseudopattern (that's a Gnu Awk extension; it's possibly to implement by trying the argument number, but it's a lot easier to not have to do so.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.. That's much more advanced awk than I've ever done before. Is there an equivalent of, say, `${FILENAME##/}`? This is really neat, I'm on the right track. I really appreciate when people like you that are very much my senior go out of their way to talk to me. I try to pay that forward whenever I'm able.

Comment: Do you mean `${FILENAME##*/}` (that is, the same as the basename utility)? In that case, the answer unfortunately is not really but you can use a regex: `gensub(/.*\//, "", 1, FILENAME)` (`gensub` is another Gnu extension.)

Comment: Or you could use this slightly cheeky hack which I think will work in any awk: `a[split(FILENAME, a, "/")]`. `split` splits it's first argument into its second argument using the supplied separator (which can be a regex) and returns the field count. In this case, I'm counting on the array existing by the time the subscript is used. I'd use `split` to split off the comment, as well.

Comment: @rici not sure if I did a good job or not.. You can see it at https://github.com/onwsk8r/golang-build-scripts/blob/master/mkfile_help.awk